# I need to FILTER rows based on a specific Users list (Google sheet - App script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 Tabs in my spread sheet "Leads" tab and "User" tab, i need google sheet to detect the user Email and compare it to the table in the User tab, if the Email is contained in the User tab it must get the name attached to that Email (example concluded in the images) then filter the rows in "Leads" tab based on that name :)
the users names are listed in a dropdown list in "column O" (column 15) in the "Leads" tab.

Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would like to clarify what you would like to accomplish. Let's say the name `Khaled` is selected from the dropdown in the column `O` in the `Leads` sheet. The email address specified in the `B1` cell of the `Users` sheet would be populated in column `N` of the `Leads` sheet. Would that be correct?

Comment: Use correct tags

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Comment: What part of this do you not understand how to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function filterdataByUsers() {
  //build object whose keys are a unique list of emails and values are a unique list of names
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const lsh = ss.getSheetByName("Leads");
  const sr = 2;
  const eObj = lsh.getRange(sr, 1, lsh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, 2).getValues().reduce((a, r, i) => {
    if (i == 0) { a.pA = [] }
      if(!a.hasOwnProperty(r[1])) {
        a[r[1]] = r[0];
        a.pA.push(r[1])
      }
    return a;
  }, {})
  const email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  //return data for email if it exists and it's in the above object list
  if(email && ~eObj.pA.indexOf(email)) {
    const filteredRows = lsh.getRange(sr,1,lsh.getLastRow() - sr + 1,lsh.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(r => r[0] == eObj[email]);
    //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(filteredRows))
    return filteredRows
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(`Email: ${email} not found`)
  }
}
```

Comment: nop, didn't work :(

Comment: It worked for me with my test data.  So I can't fix what is not broken

Comment: it really didn't work for me but i'm gonna give it another shot and see how it goes